# Should hashCode() return an object's unique ID

Tags: java, kotlin, hashcode

In my Kotlin/Java project, I have written some model classes that inherit an abstract class `BaseItem`:

```
/**
 * All data model classes should implement this
 */
abstract class BaseItem {

    /**
     * A unique integer identifier used to represent the data item in the database.
     */
    abstract val id: Int

    override fun equals(other: Any?) = (other is BaseItem) && id == other.id

}
```

These model classes will be used to represent data from a database. In the database, there is an ID column that contains unique integer identifiers.

So when I use the model classes, it is guaranteed that the `id` property of each will unique.

After reading this the Java specification for `hashCode()`:

> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of an application, the `hashCode` method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

My question is:

**Is it good practice to return this unique identifier in `hashCode()`?**

*Note: I am aware that in Kotlin, we can use [`data` classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) so that the compiler automatically derives predefined members like `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `toString()`, etc, but `abstract` classes cannot be `data` classes. (However, I could make subclasses of `BaseItem` `data` classes - I'm not sure whether or not this would be the better option for this use case).*

Comment: Given that implementation of `equals`, you more or less have no choice.

Comment: I would rather worry about your equals() method: it should not return true when comparing, say, a User with ID 1 with an Order with ID 1. An Order and a User should never be equal: they're not the same thing at all, even though they extend BaseItem

Comment: @JBNizet That's a very valid point - I did not think of that. Would it be appropriate to have an abstract `getType()` function which returns an integer based on what kind of `BaseItem` it is? Or do you think it would be better to use the standard implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` provided by Kotlin's [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html).

Comment: No. I'd let subclasses implement equals (and hashCode) as they need to. Whether it's a good idea or not to use the ID for that depends on the context, the constraints of the persistence framework (if any), etc. For example, it's common to have the ID being null, and only being populated once auto-generated by the database. In that case, you can't really use the ID for equals() and hashCode(). Sometimes, not having equals() and hashCode() (i.e. use the one from java.lang.Object) is the correct thing to do.

Comment: It's a bad idea to carry database surrogate integer keys in the object model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your abstract `BaseClass` is for data classes (a.k.a. value classes) it should define `equals` and `hashCode` as `abstract` and force the implementing, concrete classes to implement them. e.g.:

```
abstract class BaseItem {
    abstract val id: Int
    abstract override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean
    abstract override fun hashCode(): Int
}

data class Person(override val id: Int, val name: String) : BaseItem()

data class Product(
        override val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val cost: BigDecimal
) : BaseItem()
```

Implementing these functions in the base class and not overriding them in the concrete sub-classes can lead to violations on the [`equals`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/equals.html) & [`hashCode`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/hash-code.html) contracts.

Here is an example of symmetry violation if you do not force sub-classes to implement `equals`/`hashCode`:

```
abstract class BaseItem {
    abstract val id: Int
    override fun equals(other: Any?) = (other is BaseItem) && id == other.id
    override fun hashCode() = id
}

class Person(override val id: Int, val name: String) : BaseItem() {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return (other is Person) && id == other.id && name == other.name
    }

    override fun hashCode() = 31 * (31 + id.hashCode()) + name.hashCode()
}

class Product(
        override val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val cost: BigDecimal
) : BaseItem()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val baseItem1: BaseItem = Person(1, "Oliver")
    val baseItem2: BaseItem = Product(1, "grease", BigDecimal.TEN)
    println(baseItem1 == baseItem2) // false
    println(baseItem2 == baseItem1) // true
}
```

If `equals`/`hashCode` were implemented according to their contracts then both equality checks would always return the same result (`true` or `false`, in this case it should be `false` as `Product` should also override these functions and check that `other` is also a `Product` and check each relevant property, etc.).

See "Item 8: Obey the general contract when overriding equals" and "Item 9: Always override hashCode when you override equals" in *Effective Java, Second Edition* by Joshua Bloch for more details on these contracts and the problems around different approaches to hierarchical value classes.

Comment: Why would it lead to violations?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I've updated my answer to include an example of a violation.

Comment: Yup, fair!  (Though one does see the base-class `equals` pattern in Java standard libraries, e.g. `AbstractList`).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Good point. This only applies to data/value classes. I've updated my answer to clarify such. _Effective Java_ also points out that there are some valid use cases of inheriting `equals`/`hashCode` from an abstract class and uses. e.g. `AbstractList`, `AbstractSet`, etc.

Comment: @mfulton26 Thank you - such a detailed answer! I've learnt a lot more about `hashCode()` and `equals()` and the examples are helpful as well. I did read _Effective Java_ a while ago, but I suppose I've forgotten a lot of it so I may read through it again. ;)

Comment: Well, if you implement `hashCode` and `equals` in the abstract class properly, you would not have such a symmetry violation. For instance, if you had a `getClass()` method in Kotlin (such as the one that exists in Java), you could check in the `BaseItem`'s `equals` method that the other object is of the same class as this instance, and then check the ID. No violation of any kind.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner if you did not add any properties then yes but the moment you at a property you must sacrifice something: symmetry, transitivity, etc.